# Cuda triple nested for loop assignement

Tags: c++, for-loop, cuda, nested-loops

I'm trying to convert c++ code into Cuda code and I've got the following triple nested for loop that will fill an array for further OpenGL rendering (i'm simply creating a coordinate vertices array):

```
for(int z=0;z<263;z++) {                    
       for(int y=0;y<170;y++) {
           for(int x=0;x<170;x++) {
               g_vertex_buffer_data_3[i]=(float)x+0.5f;
               g_vertex_buffer_data_3[i+1]=(float)y+0.5f;
               g_vertex_buffer_data_3[i+2]=-(float)z+0.5f; 
               i+=3;            
           }
       }
   }
```

I would like to get faster operations and so I'll use Cuda for some operations like the one listed above. I want to create one block for each iteration of the outermost loop and since the inner loops have iterations of 170 * 170 = 28900 total iterations, assign one thread to each innermost loop iteration. I converted the c++ code into this (it's just a small program that i made to understand how to use Cuda):

```
__global__ void mykernel(int k, float *buffer) {
int idz=blockIdx.x;
int idx=threadIdx.x;
int idy=threadIdx.y;

buffer[k]=idx+0.5;
buffer[k+1]=idy+0.5;
buffer[k+2]=idz+0.5;
k+=3;

}

int main(void) {
  int dim=3*170*170*263;
  float* g_vertex_buffer_data_2 = new float[dim];
  float* g_vertex_buffer_data_3;
  int i=0;

  HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&g_vertex_buffer_data_3, sizeof(float)*dim));

  dim3 dimBlock(170, 170);

  dim3 dimGrid(263);

  mykernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(i, g_vertex_buffer_data_3);

  HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(&g_vertex_buffer_data_2,g_vertex_buffer_data_3,sizeof(float)*dim,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
    printf("g_vertex_buffer_data_2[%d]=%f\n",j,g_vertex_buffer_data_2[j]);
  }
  cudaFree(g_vertex_buffer_data_3);

  return 0;

}
```

Trying to launch it I get a segmenation fault. Do you know what am i doing wrong?
I think the problem is that threadIdx.x and threadIdx.y grow at the same time, while I would like to have threadIdx.x to be the inner one and threadIdx.y to be the outer one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot wrong here, but the source of the segfault is this:

```
cudaMemcpy(&g_vertex_buffer_data_2,g_vertex_buffer_data_3,
                sizeof(float)*dim,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

You either want

```
cudaMemcpy(&g_vertex_buffer_data_2[0],g_vertex_buffer_data_3,
                sizeof(float)*dim,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

or

```
cudaMemcpy(g_vertex_buffer_data_2,g_vertex_buffer_data_3,
                sizeof(float)*dim,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Once you fix that you will notice that the kernel is actually never launching with an invalid launch error. This is because a block size of `(170,170)` is illegal. CUDA has a 1024 threads per block limit on all current hardware.

There might well be other problems in your code. I stopped looking after I found these two.

Comment: I edited the first thing, thank you! Now i try with the second one, i have to find the right way to set the number of blocks per grid and threads per block. For my triple nested loop, should i use threadsId and blockId as indices for g_vertex_buffer_data_3 or should i use different indices that i increase at every loop?

Comment: Instead of working with such a big data set you could start with a smaller data set to fix the other issues you have, e.g.: k+=3 is not doing what you expect, test for buffer overflow and g_vertex_buffer_data_2 is leaking.
After that you can e.g. partition the entire data set and call your CUDA kernel multiple times, to workaround the HW limitation. But first get the logic right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can i do k+=3 with CUDA? I mean, how can i tell Cuda to do what would do k+=3 in c++?

Comment: @NicolòCogno: Please don't edit to change your question after it has already been answered. This isn't your personal help thread. It is a question. Which I answered and you have now changed into something else. This isn't how [SO] works. If you have a different question (and it seems that you do) ask a new question.,