# Jump to the next block in a for loop Cuda

Tags: c++, for-loop, cuda

I'm trying to convert c++ code into Cuda code and I've got the following triple nested for loop that will fill an array for further OpenGL rendering (i'm simply creating a coordinate vertices array):

```
for(int z=0;z<263;z++) {                    
   for(int y=0;y<170;y++) {
       for(int x=0;x<170;x++) {
           g_vertex_buffer_data_3[i]=(float)x+0.5f;
           g_vertex_buffer_data_3[i+1]=(float)y+0.5f;
           g_vertex_buffer_data_3[i+2]=-(float)z+0.5f; 
           i+=3;            
       }
   }
}
```

I would like to get faster operations and so I'll use Cuda for some operations like the one listed above. I want to create one block for each point and since every point has 3 coordinates, I want to have blocks of 3 threads each. I would like to use this configuration because I have got a 3d matrix of 7600700 points so I thought that the most logic thing was to create a 3d matrix made up of blocks and then use 3 threads in each block for the x, y, z coordinates of each point. I converted the c++ code into this (it's just a small program that I made to understand how to use Cuda and here I'm using just a few points):

```
__global__ void mykernel(int k, float *buffer, int size) {
    const unsigned long int blockId = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z;

    const unsigned long int threadId = (blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)*blockDim.x;
    if(threadId<size ) {
      buffer[threadId]=blockIdx.x+0.5;
      buffer[threadId+1]=blockIdx.y+0.5;
      buffer[threadId+2]=blockIdx.z+0.5;
    }
 }

int main(void) {
  int dim=3*5*5*7;
  float* g_vertex_buffer_data_2 = new float[dim];
  float* g_vertex_buffer_data_3;
  int i=0;

  HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&g_vertex_buffer_data_3, sizeof(float)*dim));

  dim3 dimBlock(3);

  dim3 dimGrid(5,5,7);

  mykernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(i, g_vertex_buffer_data_3, dim);

  HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(g_vertex_buffer_data_2,g_vertex_buffer_data_3,sizeof(float)*dim,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  cudaFree(g_vertex_buffer_data_3);

  return 0;

}
```

With this code i get something not too bad. The problem is that after the if statement i would like the code to "skip" to the next block because i'm getting the same result three times (i've got three threads so the code passes through each of them before jumping to the next block).
I try to explain myself with a little piece of the output:

```
g_buffer_data_2[0]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[0]=0.5               
g_buffer_data_2[1]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[1]=0.5             
g_buffer_data_2[2]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[2]=0.5             
g_buffer_data_2[3]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[3]=1.5             
g_buffer_data_2[4]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[4]=0.5             
g_buffer_data_2[5]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[5]=0.5             
g_buffer_data_2[6]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[6]=2.5             
g_buffer_data_2[7]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[7]=0.5             
g_buffer_data_2[8]=0.5        g_buffer_data_2[8]=0.5        
g_buffer_data_2[9]=1.5        g_buffer_data_2[9]=3.5         
g_buffer_data_2[10]=0.5       g_buffer_data_2[10]=0.5         
g_buffer_data_2[11]=0.5       g_buffer_data_2[11]=0.5
g_buffer_data_2[12]=1.5       g_buffer_data_2[12]=4.5                   
[...]
```

On the left there's what i get, while on the right there's what i would like to have.
What should i modify? Should i use only one thread per block? But will this decrease the performances?

Comment: English is not my main language so tell me if something is not clear

Comment: From this question and [your last one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38097435/5085250) my recommendation is to read a book or tutorial about CUDA and implement some examples before you start with your actual problem. I don't think your problem can be solved to your satisfaction on SO because you don't know the basic concepts of CUDA programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not that familiar with CUDA, you could start from constructing at least `dim/3` threads where each thread only fill one point.

```
dim3 size(170, 170, 263);
```

3 threads per block is still much too small to get the peak performance. A common choice is to use a power of 2 close to the maximum threads per block of your device. It's a good practice to use `warpSize` threads on `.x` dim. The threads should be organized with 3-D block and grid to match your loop `x`, `y` and `z`:

```
dim3 dimBlock(32, 4, 4);
dim3 dimGrid((size.x + dimBlock.x - 1) / dimBlock.x,
             (size.z + dimBlock.y - 1) / dimBlock.y,
             (size.z + dimBlock.z - 1) / dimBlock.z);
```

On the other hand, your task is a good situation to use `float3` to simplify the indexing:

```
float3* g_vertex_buffer_data_3;
cudaMalloc((void**) &g_vertex_buffer_data_3,
           sizeof(float3) * size.x * size.y * size.z);
```

So the kernel should be like this,

```
__global__ void mykernel(float3 *buffer, dim3 size) {
  int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
  int z = blockDim.z * blockIdx.z + threadIdx.z;
  if (x < size.x && y < size.y && z < size.z) {
    float3 buf;
    buf.x = x + 0.5f;
    buf.y = y + 0.5f;
    buf.z = -z + 0.5f;
    buffer[(z * size.y + y) * size.x + x] = buf;
  }
}
```

and this is how you launch it.

```
mykernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(g_vertex_buffer_data_3, size);
```